# Business Central SaaS app rejecting REST call with wrong scope

Tags: dynamics-business-central

I am trying to communicate with a Business Central SaaS application through Postman. I've created an App registration for this in the involved customer environment. With the information I got there I filled in the authorization (type OAuth 2.0) to get a token. I am able to successfully get a token however, when I actually do a GET call to Business Central, it fails giving me the error: **'The credentials provided are incorrect'**.

I've done some digging and I see something strange in the scope of the token:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4SSO.png)

As you can see, the scope listed is 'Financials.ReadWrite.All user_impersonation'. This is strange, because I've added the value 'https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/user_impersonation' as scope. I've also tried it with the 'https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/.default' value as scope, but that is giving me the same error and the same scope value in the token.

For further information I will include a screenshot of the API permissions in the App registration:

As you can see here, the Financials.ReadWrite.All permission is not included here and should not be selected in the scope of the token. I've also tried a Business Central call with the Financials.ReadWrite.All permission included in the API permissions but that also results in the 'The credentials provided are incorrect' error.

Anyone have an idea what is going wrong here?

Comment: For some reason it will not allow me to include the screenshot of the API permissions. The configured permissions are the following:

Dynamics 365 Business Central (1): user_impersonation (delegated and granted by admin)

Comment: Why is the title of the question Postman is using the wrong scope? It does seem that Postman has nothing to do with the scope of the token, correct?

Comment: The token is created by Postman, thus, it has everything to do with Postman.

Comment: Postman is "issuing" the token? Or are you using postman to "retrieve" the token from the api.businesscentral.dynamics.com? From your previous comment one would derive you're contacting postman's API to get a Postman token. That's not what I read from the original post.

Comment: TL:DR: Postman is just the means to test the API you're working with. You could replace postman by curl, any programming language, etc. The issue is not with the Postman token (making the title quite misleading). The token is being issued by https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com. Because you're getting a non-generic error (like 401), it means it's something related to the call you're making and the token you're using. The question is still valid, I just questioned the title, because I try to help on Postman questions, and this one has nothing to do with it. Postman is just the transport.

Comment: Understood. Thank you for your reaction Bitoiu. I will be less misleading with the title in the future.

Comment: No worries at all, it can be edited. The thing is, the more focused/accurate your question is the right eyes will get. For I example, I came to this question because it was tagged as Postman, so if you can potentially add more tags around the business application or details of it maybe you can get more help.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of a colleague I've been able to solve this problem. Apparently the usage of the 'Inherit auth from parent' authorization type didn't work well in my case. I selected this as type but, for some reason, it didn't use the configuration that was stored there. I had to configure the authorization on the request itself before I got it to work.

Very strange.